# Close blocking client connection of webscokettpp client from C# UI application

Tags: c++, sockets, websocket, libwebsockets

I am using webscokettpp c++ client to read data posted from a web-server. I have a c# UI appication with a test button which calls c++ client dll to get and display the data posted on the socket. When test button is clicked data is posted properly on UI for second time I want to close existing connection, open new connection to get results again. But after the first run  program never returns from c.run(); in following code. I am using a example from https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp/blob/master/examples/echo_client/echo_client.cpp

```
 #include <websocketpp/config/asio_no_tls_client.hpp>
 #include <websocketpp/client.hpp>

 #include <iostream>

    typedef websocketpp::client<websocketpp::config::asio_client> client;

    using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_1;
    using websocketpp::lib::placeholders::_2;
    using websocketpp::lib::bind;

    // pull out the type of messages sent by our config
    typedef websocketpp::config::asio_client::message_type::ptr message_ptr;

    // This message handler will be invoked once for each incoming message. It
    // prints the message and then sends a copy of the message back to the server.
    void on_message(client* c, websocketpp::connection_hdl hdl, message_ptr msg) {
        std::cout << "on_message called with hdl: " << hdl.lock().get()
                  << " and message: " << msg->get_payload()
                  << std::endl;

         if(pt.get<std::string>("test") = "close" ){
          //Code reaches here after end of first run but never comes out of c.run()
            c->close(hdl, websocketpp::close::status::normal, "Success");
            hdl.reset();
         }

        websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;

        c->send(hdl, msg->get_payload(), msg->get_opcode(), ec);
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Echo failed because: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
        }
    }

    int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
        // Create a client endpoint
        client c;

        std::string uri = "ws://localhost:9002";

        if (argc == 2) {
            uri = argv[1];
        }

        try {
            // Set logging to be pretty verbose (everything except message payloads)
            c.set_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::all);
            c.clear_access_channels(websocketpp::log::alevel::frame_payload);

            // Initialize ASIO
            c.init_asio();

            // Register our message handler
            c.set_message_handler(bind(&on_message,&c,::_1,::_2));

            websocketpp::lib::error_code ec;
            client::connection_ptr con = c.get_connection(uri, ec);
            if (ec) {
                std::cout << "could not create connection because: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                return 0;
            }

            // Note that connect here only requests a connection. No network messages are
            // exchanged until the event loop starts running in the next line.
            c.connect(con);

            // Start the ASIO io_service run loop
            // this will cause a single connection to be made to the server. c.run()
            // will exit when this connection is closed.
            c.run();
        } catch (websocketpp::exception const & e) {
            std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

I am trying to figure out a way to main method to come out of c.run() when condition if(pt.get("test") = "close" ) happens.

Comment: I would guess that the echo_client is made to work with the echo_server and not any webserver.

Comment: Err, `break`? `return`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call run() on a separate thread while you use the client; this will then allow you to stop the client gracefully when you are done on a separate thread. IIRC then run() will then exit meaning that you can close the thread and start all over again when you need to.

See [this FAQ](https://docs.websocketpp.org/faq.html), particularly the "How do I cleanly exit an Asio transport based program" section. Stopping the exe to forcibly close the connection is a bad idea and can lead to subtle bugs.

> The Asio transport based clients and servers use the Asio library's underlying io_service to handle asyncronous networking operations. The standard behavior of the io_service is to run until there are no async operations left and then return. WebSocket++, when using the Asio transport, behaves like a standard Asio application. If you want your WebSocket++/Asio based program to stop network operations and cleanly close all sockets you will want to do the following:
>
> For servers, call websocketpp::transport::asio::endpoint::stop_listening to initiate the closing of the server listening socket.
> For clients, if you have engaged perpetual mode with websocketpp::transport::asio::endpoint::start_perpetual, disable it with websocketpp::transport::asio::endpoint::stop_perpetual.
> For both, run websocketpp::endpoint::close or websocketpp::connection::close on all currently outstanding connections. This will initiate the WebSocket closing handshake for these connections
> Wait. Asio is asyncronous. When the calls to the above methods (stop_listening, close, etc) complete the server will still be listening, the connections will still be active until the io_service gets around to asyncronously processing the socket and WebSocket protocol closing handshakes. The io_service::run method will exit cleanly and automatically when all operations are complete.
> WARNING: Asio's io_service has a method called stop. WebSocket++ wraps this method as websocketpp::transport::asio::endpoint::stop. While this operation has a benign sounding name, it is a powerful and destructive operation that should only be used in special cases. If you are using io_service::stop or endpoint::stop without a very good reason your program is likely broken and may exhibit erratic behavior. Specifically, io_service::stop stops the processing of events entirely. This does not give current operations (such as socket closing handshakes) the opportunity to finish. It will leave your sockets in a dangling state that may invoke operating system level timeouts or other errors.